# Get all possible DFS visits from a given start

Tags: python, permutation, graph-theory

let's say I have the following undirected graph:

- V = {v1,v2,v3,v4}
- E = {{v1,v2}, {v1,v3}, {v2,v4}, {v3,v4}}

If I run a DFS starting in v1 without a destination, just to visit every point of the graph, there are two possibilities: v1->v2->v4->v3 or v1->v3->v4->v2.

I wrote a short python program that does one path of DFS:

```py
def custom_dfs(path, graph, current):    
    if(current in path):
        return None
    
    path.append(current)
    
    for possibility in graph[current]:
        custom_dfs(path, graph, possibility)
```

Now my question is, how to extend this so that I can account for all possibilities, in other word to run DFS on each connected node?

Comment: Your looking for an algorithm to enumerate all spanning trees in a graph.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the algorithm to find a spanning tree

```
add start node to span
while nodes outside span
   loop n1 over nodes in span
       loop n2 over nodes not in span
           if n1-n2 link present
               add n2 to span
```

Modified like this should ( I haven't tested it ) enumerate all possible spans

```
add start node to span
push partial span to stack
while stack not empty
   pop partial span from stack
   new_span_found = false
   while nodes outside span
       loop n1 over nodes in span
           loop n2 over nodes not in span
               if n1-n2 link present
                    add n2 to span 
                    push partial span to stack
                    new_span_found = true
   
   if new_span_found
        add span to output
```